# Force matplotlib grid on narrow log axis

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, I am unable to get a grid in the following code (which has a log y axis spanning less than a decade without crossing a power of 10).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
x = np.geomspace(0.001,5,101)
y = 10**(-0.2-0.05*(np.log10(x)+0.5)**2)
plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
yticks = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6] # should not need to be set!
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(yticks)) # why so complicated?
plt.grid()
```

unless, I remove

```
axes.grid : True
```

from my matplotlibrc. Is there a solution that does not involve editing my matplotlibrc file every time I run into a narrow log axis, nor deleting `axes.grid : True` in my matplotlibrc file, which would force me include `plt.grid` in my plots?

My other lines involving grids in my matplotlibrc are

```
axes.grid.axis       : both    ## which axis the grid should apply to
axes.grid.which      : major   ## gridlines at major, minor or both ticks
grid.linestyle       : dotted  ## was solid
```

Comment: With `axes.grid.which  = 'major'` only grid lines are shown for the major ticks. With `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator` you add major ticks.  With the default settings, the loglocator only has major ticks at the powers of 10, and minor ticks inbetween.  Maybe you want `set_major_locator(LogLocator(subs=range(1,10))`?

Comment: note you can "access" your `stylelib` with the dictionary `matplotlib.rcParams`. So you can just say `matplotlib.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True` in your code and not have to mess with the other file at all

Comment: @JohanC: thanks for the tip, which is useful, even if it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @A J Biffl: your tip is interesting, as one can place ```matplotlib.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True``` at the top of the code and not have to type ```plt.grid()``` for every plot. A more agreeable solution that I just discovered is to keep ```axes.grid : True``` in my matplotlibrc and for this particular code, use ```plt.grid(True)``` instead of ```plt.grid()```. But I don't understand why there is this incompatibility between the line in the matplotlibrc and the need to insert ```True``` in the ```plt.grid()``` line.